# A Big Crossword Development

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle, pattern, rhyme, crosswords

A big crossword development exists, for Gerbil has indeed journeyed knowingly long, may now openly present, quickly, really strange tales under very weird xeric young zips...

[image]

> $1$ is simply the indefinite article
>   While $2$ is existing, such as any particle
>   $3$ can be worn, it’s a type of hat
>   $4$ is an entrance, such as that to a flat
>   Now $5$ is next, it is to go in
>   $6$ means weak, such as being hit on the shin
>   $7$ is moan and 7 is whine
>   $8$ is funny, 8 is good times
>   $9$ isn’t real, its all a dupe
>   $10$ is a writer who looks for scoops
>   Unit of pressure to $11$ is tied
>   $12$’s running lengthwise, from side to side
>   $13$ of many cells is made
>   Under 100 nm is $14$, a tech upgrade
>   $15$ is emotional, but over the top
>   $16$ are fossil scientists, the ground is their shop
>   $17$ is 10 to the power of one-five-three
>   $18$ is a measure of reflectiveness on a sample, and to what degree
>   $19$ is great concentration on a particular skill
>   $20$’s relating to rock formations after a tectonic thrill
>   And lastly $21$ is belonging to 10 to the power of one-five-six
>   You’re not finished yet, up my sleeve are some tricks
>
> **Spot the patterns in the crossword you see
>
>   And tell me, what would the answer to $22$ be?**

Comment: So... was the border irrelevant?

Comment: The answer to 25 would be "[yesterday-today-and-tomorrow](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/yesterday-today-and-tomorrow)," (the name of _[Brunfelsia pauciflora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brunfelsia_pauciflora)_), although its dashes would make it tricky to fit into a crossword.

Comment: @Deusovi well, it didn’t add anything to the puzzle no. It was more just decoration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The pattern is:

> The word's number equals the length of the word along with the position of the first letter according to the English alphabet

Completed crossword (credit to [buildstarted](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63030/40060), [Sid](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63032/40060), and [pfg](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63033/40060) for several of these answer):

> [image: Completed crossword puzzle]

And tell me, what would the answer to 22 be?

> vaginoperineorrhaphies, as it is the only 22 letter word beginning with V (again thanks to [pfg](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/63033/40060)!) [OPs Note:  Impressively, some others were found but in research this was he only one which seemed to be valid, and was the only one I found when I made this puzzle]

Comment: 6 and 9 wrong... rest correct

Comment: Btw, it will probably be easy to solve the other clues by filling in some of the crossword

Comment: Buildstarted's answer has quite a few correct answers you could add. Good progress!

Comment: All right in latest update

Comment: The one you are missing has been found, and is just missing two letters on the end. Also, remember to include the final answer with reasoning :)

Comment: @pfg has the correct final answer. Simply only 22 letter word beginning with v (though others have been found, this is the only apparent valid word)

Comment: I was thinking the answer was a lot more cryptic than that, tried adding/removing combinations of letters from the words in the crossword/ your first sentence to no avail. Great puzzle :)

Comment: I wanted to add another layer of encryption for a definite final answer, but it’s hard to include too many other patterns when you are dealing with 20+ letter words having to start with letters such as u and v :)

Answer (score 4):

First:

> The gimmick is that Clue no.1 starts with "a', clue no.2 with "b" and so on. Next, the clue number suggests their respective enumeration. The initial lines of the puzzle which appear gibberish but I think those have all the letters of the alphabets which point to these ideas. Now,

Here's what I have done so far:

> [image]

Remaining Clues:

> 5 is most probably "ENTER" which is a bit odd since that's what the clue says.
>  13 is probably microglobular or something biology-related but I can't seem to figure it out right now.
>  I am completely stuck on 15, 20 and 21 though.

Comment: 17, 14, 9 are wrong, otherwise you have most of the puzzle. (5 is right, I'll recheck the wording. Probably wrong cos I tried to make it rhyme)

Comment: Got 9. Hilariously 17 has just the right cross-letter for 19 to be correct in spite of being wrong. :P

Comment: pretty unbelievable :P

Answer (score 4):

1

> a

2

> be

3

> cap

4

> door

5

> enter

6

> flimsy

7

> grumble

8

> humorous

9

> imitation

10

> journalist

11

> kilocalorie? not pressure

12

> longitudinal

13

> multicellular

14

> nanotechnology

15

> orthopsychiatry

16

> paleoclimatology

17

> quinquagintillion

18

> retroreflectometer

19

> superspecialization

20

> tectonostratigrapher/tectonostratigraphic

21

> unquinquagintillionth

22

> vaginoperineorrhaphies

I hope this is right

Comment: 6, 9, 11, 15, 16, 18 are wrong. Second guess for 20 is correct

Answer (score 3):

My original guess which I thought fit the pattern *and* the rhyme

> vigintioctingentillion Spot the patterns in the crossword you see And tell me what would the answer to 22 be it will be 10 to the power of 2-4-6-3

Actual answer by @pfg:

> vaginoperineorrhaphies

1

> 1

2

> be

3

> cap

4

> door

5

> enter

6

> feeble?

7

> grumble

8

> humorous

9

> imaginary

10

> journalist

11

> kilopascals

12

> longitudinal

13

> multicellular

14

> nanotechnology

15

> oversentimental

16

> palaeontologists

17

> quinquagintillion

18

> representativeness

19

> superspecialization

20

> tectonostratigraphic

21

> unquinquagintillion

22

> vaginoperineorrhaphies

Comment: Ony 13 wrong out of answered clues

Comment: 17 right, 21 two letters off (my mistake, edited question now)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil 10^2463 vigintioctingentillion is not a valid word? :)

Answer (score 1):

1 is

> 'a'

12 is

> Longitudinal

19 is

> Superspecialization

21 is

> unquinquagintillionth

Comment: Nope. Once you spot the pattern by solving the easier ones, then the slightly more ambiguous ones will become obvious

Comment: Number 1 is simple. Look up 'indefinite article'

Comment: 19 right, 13 wrong